# how to make two options appear in each one row while mapping over number of options react js

Tags: reactjs

here iam trying to render four options for a question from one file but i need to make 2 options appear in one row and next two options in another row while iterating over the options iam not able to figure it out how to do it . here is my code.

`

```
 {
       data.options.map(option => (
           <div>
             <input type='radio' name='option' value={option.text} />
             <div>
               <span>{option.text}</span>
             </div>
          </div>
        )
     )
 }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class to your `div` wrapper to make it float, and surround that div to include an element that clears the float every two options.

You can check a working example on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jalissa/o30ytwps/).

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the approach.

**Wrap the map in a function.**

```
 this.fetchOptions =(options) =>  
       options.map(option => (
           <div>
             <input type='radio' name='option' value={option.text} />
             <div>
               <span>{option.text}</span>
             </div>
          </div>
        )
     )
```

**Call the method two times passing the data as below.**

```
 render(){
    <div>
      <div className="Row">{this.fetchOptions(data.options.slice(0,2))}</div>
      <div className="Row">{this.fetchOptions(data.options.slice(2,4))}</div>
    </div>
 }
```

Now that DOM is wrapped with two div, appropriate class can be applied.

Hope it helps :)